# If polygons share a border in a shapefile, create an attribute that links them

Tags: python, geospatial, networkx, geopandas, network-analysis

Goal: Create a network derived from a shapefile where the nodes are the centroids of each polygon (~900) and the links represent where these polygons/nodes share a border.

I have used Geopandas to read in a shapefile with ~900 polygons and have calculated the centroids of those polygons.

Using Networkx, I have then used those centroid points as the nodes in a new network.

I now need to create a link between every pair of nodes that share a border.

Can someone please advise how best to approach this using Geopandas, Networkx, or other geospatial and/or network packages in Python? Sample code would be helpful.

```
##### Open input Districts shapefile using GeoPandas #####
polys = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\mrich\gadm36_TUR_2.shp")
print(polys.head())
#polys.plot()

points = polys.copy()
# Calculate centroids of polygons
points['geometry'] = points['geometry'].centroid
print(points.head())
#points.plot()
#plt.show()

# Write centroids to new Shapefile
points.to_file('centroids.shp')

##### Create network #####
centroids = gpd.read_file(r"C:\Users\mrich\centroids.shp")
print(centroids['geometry'].head())
# draw graph
graph = nx.read_shp('centroids.shp', simplify=True, geom_attrs=True, strict=True)
nx.draw(graph, node_size = 2)
plt.show()
```

Comment: couple of things: 1) https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve 2) why do you compute the centroids, write them to a file, then read that file back? 3) what problem are you having? Is the code throwing an error? Do you need help building lines? Have you read shapely's documentation on building geometries?

Comment: You might want to ask this as gis.stackexchange.com (with more details)

Comment: You might want to use `libpysal` to calculate Rook or Queen contiguity weights. That will effectively generate the network you are looking for. If you want to use it with `networkx` you can easily convert it. Look at https://libpysal.readthedocs.io/en/latest/.